# Getting Json Titled json Array without using pojo , bean, or getter and setter

Tags: java, json, servlets, gson

Hi I've just started to use Json.
My problem is I want json array in following form

```
  [ { "id" : "1", "name" : "India" },{ "id" : "2", "name" : "Pakistan" },{ "id" : "3", "name" : "China" },{ "id" : "4", "name" : "Japan" },{ "id" : "5", "name" : "Russia" } ]
```

I want id and name title for every value.
Then biggest problem is when I am sending this json to ajax using servlet I am getting nothing (using this code)

```
    List<stateList> sl = new ArrayList<stateList>();//ststeList is getters n setters obj
    sl.add(new stateList("1","India"));
    Gson js = new Gson();
    js.toJson(sl);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(js.toString());
```

but if I use string object I am getting the value but without titles i.e (id,name)

```
       {"1":"India","2":"Pak","3":"China"}
```

Code is

```
    Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
    m.put("1", "India");
    m.put("2", "Pak");
    m.put("3", "China");

    String js = new Gson().toJson(m);
```

So finally I want above most json to send to ajax.There is no proble with ajax code its working fine with this type

Answer (score 1):

Use `entrySet` to get the keys. Just loop through the entries

**Code :**

```
JsonParser p = new JsonParser();
JsonObject result = p.parse(file).getAsJsonObject();
Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = result.entrySet();
for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entrySet) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey()); //this gives you the keys.
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks but I am using Gson, I'll try this also

Comment: yourwelcome, I prefer this way, it's easier to get keys and also more easier if you use Java8, don't forget to add json-simple lib to your project too http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm - Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

Ok after lots of toiling I got the solution which is already hidden in the class I built previously.

```
 class stateList
 {
   private String id;
   private String StateName;
   stateList s;
   public stateList(String id, String StateName)
   {
     this.id = id;
     this.StateName = StateName;
   }
   public String toString() {
    return "id = " +id+ ", stateName = " +StateName; //solution
   }
  }
```

just call the stateList's toString();

```
         //code 2 line 5
    js = new Gson().toJson(sl.toString());
```